# ¿Como guardar y recuperar datos? javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola verán tengo este formulario en el que en esta parte del cogido tengo dos funciones que sirven para guardar y la otra para recuperar los datos.El error aparece cuando hago clic en el botón para guardar los datos del formulario y luego intento recuperarlo a través del DNI, lo cierto es que después de muchos cambios no puedo averiguar por qué esto sucede.

más exactamente esto es lo que me da el error

Edición: Gracias al usuario que propuso una solución esto corrige algunos fallos pero ahora el error que aparece es este

> Uncaught ReferenceError: datos is not defined

> ```
> guardar file:///f:/javascript recuperacion/EJER formulario/finalizar.js:42
> ```

Pasare el código en las partes que creo que no funcionan y marcare donde aparece el error

Aquí en el javascrip llamado finalizar

```
function guardar() {

    console.log("entra");
    
    document.getElementById('nombre').value = datos.nombre; //Aqui aparece el error linea 42
    document.getElementById('email').value = datos.email ;
    document.getElementById('edad').value = datos.edad;
    document.getElementById('etsex').value = datos.etsex;
    document.getElementById('tlf').value = datos.tlf;
    document.getElementById('estado_civil').value = datos.estado_civil;
    document.getElementById('seleccion').value = datos.seleccion;
    document.getElementById('txtdesc').value = datos.txtdesc;

    


    sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI, JSON.stringify(datos));

    
    datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI));



}

function recuperar(){
    console.log("entra");
    var guardaDNI = document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value;

    if(sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI)){
        console.log("Pilla el item")
        var datos = sessionStorage.getItem(guardaDNI);
        console.log(datos.modalidad);
    }else{
        window.alert("No hay datos del DNI : "+guardaDNI);
        document.getElementById('guardaDNI').value = "";
    }

}
```

Aqui el archivo llamado inicia

```
window.onload = function(){  
    var eBtn = document.getElementById("Enviar");
    var vBtn = document.getElementById("validar");
    var dBtn = document.getElementById("borrar");
    /*var desplegar = document.getElementById("desplegar");*/
    var gBtn = document.getElementById("guardar");
    var rBtn = document.getElementById("recuperar");
    eBtn.onclick = mostrar;
   /* desplegar.onchange = desplegar;*/
    vBtn.onclick = validador;
    dBtn.onclick = reset;
    gBtn.onclick = guardar; 
    rBtn.onclick = recuperar;
    inicia();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema que veo a primera vista lo tienes aquí:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI, JSON.stringify(datos));


datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI));
```

Primero deberías de definir la variable `datos` antes de utilizarla en el `sessionStorage`, es decir quedando así el código:

```
datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI));
sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI, JSON.stringify(datos));
```

Por otro lado, estas usando algo que no es correcto en esta linea:

```
datos = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.setItem(guardaDNI));
```

Ya que `sessionStorage.setItem()` es utilizado para guardar, y no para obtener. Para este caso, tienes que utilizar: `sessionStorage.getItem()`.

Comment: voy a probar y ahora te digo a ver si lo puedo arreglar